# Formatting very large numbers in C

Tags: c, formatting

I have to output a large number, a double precision number using the following code:

```
fprintf(outFile,"           %11.0f   %d O(g(n))",factorialNotRecursive(index,factCount),factValue);
```

now the number gets so big that it jumps out of alignment further down the
list of output. Once it gets past 11 digits, the max specified it continues 
to grow larger. Is there a way to cope with this? I'm not sure how big the inputs
that will be run on this program.

Comment: Um, change `%11.0f` to something bigger, like `%20.0f` ?

Comment: Yes, knowing the input limits would help answering this question... ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I'm doing an assignment for class, and our professor is transitioning us towards c from c++ which we learned in intro courses. Again, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you cannot do it directly. You have to print to a string, then change the string.

```
/* pseudo (untested) code */

value = factorialNotRecursive(index, factCount);
/* make sure buff is large enough (or use snprintf if available) */
n = sprintf(buff, "%11.0f", value);
if (n > 11) {
    buff[10] = '+';
    buff[11] = 0;
}
fprintf(outFile,"           %s   %d O(g(n))", buff, factValue);
```